# Does 'friend' declaration affect the accessibility of members in the Base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, public, friend, protected

I am confused on the effectiveness of a `friend` declaration.

In the first example, this `friend` declaration in `Base` caused me to not get an error on `d.j` and `d.k` in the `main()` function.

However, in the second example, it seems the `friend` declaration has no impact at all. The compiler throws errors in `main()` on `d.i`, `d.j`, `d.k` as well as `d.m` and `d.n`.

It seems `public` and `protected` inheritance only matters.

Example 1:

```
struct Base
{
    friend int main(); 

public:
    int i;

protected:
    int j;

private:
    int k;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int l;
protected:
    int m;
private:
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d; 
    d.i = 1;
    d.j = 2;
    d.k = 3;
    d.l = 4;
    d.m = 5; //error
    d.n = 6; //error

    return 0;
}
```

Example 2:

```
struct Base
{
    friend int main(); 

public:
    int i;

protected:
    int j;

private:
    int k;
};

struct Derived : protected Base
{
public:
    int l;
protected:
    int m;
private:
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    Derived d; 
    d.i = 1; //error
    d.j = 2; //error
    d.k = 3; //error
    d.l = 4;
    d.m = 5; //error
    d.n = 6; //error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Base` is a protected base class of `Derived`, so the members that `Derived` inherits from `Base` can only be accessed by class `Derived` and classes derived from `Derived`. If you had a reference to class `Base` in your main function, you could access the members i, j and k, but not through a reference to `Derived`.

Comment: Before `main` can access members of `Base`, it first needs to be able to access `Base` object itself. In the first example it can, as `Base` subobject of `d` is public. In the second example it cannot, since that subobject is protected.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  so it means  accessibility priority goes first to public, protected and private inheritance and the friend. Even if we have friend in Base, with protected or private inheritance, friend has no effectiveness! But in the first example,  with pubic inheritance , main() can see the whole object, then it can only see i as the member and with friend it can see  j and k as well. Am I right? it is like a hierarchy , first object, then members and first type of inheritance and then friend.

Comment: Instead of inheritance, consider this: `struct D { protected: Base b; }; D d;` Would you expect `main` to be able to access `d.b.j` just because it's friends with `Base`? Inheritance works the same way - effectively, the derived class contains a member whose type is the base class; you just can't explicitly name that member, it gets accessed implicitly. But access rules work for this base class subobject the same way they do for a data member subobject.

Comment: @Sam: "*But in the first example, with pubic inheritance , main() can see the whole object*" No, it cannot. It can see what is *public* in `Dervied`. `Base` and `l` are public in `Derived`. It has access to the private members of `Base`, but to get access to them, it has to **see `Base`**.

Comment: Related reading: [Derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik and  NicolBolas those were really  good points.  It makes sense a lot. Thanks everyone for the help. 

All comments have been helpful. I wish I had asked this sooner. I had spent two hours trying to understand this. Now it is clear. (I also had asked ChatGPT  and the problem seemed to be too complicated for it and I kept getting wrong explanations :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d.i` is a fiction. `Derived` does not have `i` in it. What it *does* have is a `Base`, which itself has an `i` in it. To get to `d.i` therefore, one must first be able to see `Derived::Base`.

If you publicly inherit from a base class, that means any code can see the derived class's base class object. If you protectedly inherit from a base class, only code with protected access *to the derived class* can see the derived'd class's base class object.

`main` is a friend of `Base`, not `Derived`. So it has no special access to `Derived`. Therefore, if you use protected inheritance, it cannot get to `Derived::Base` and therefore cannot see `Derived::Base::i`.

Comment: "If you protectedly inherit from a base class, only code with protected access to the derived class can see the derived'd class's base class object."  would you please clarify this more? I am confused on this particular explanation.

Comment: @Sam: What don't you understand?

Comment: the part that says "only code with protected access to the derived class can see the derived'd class's base class object."  and the part says  'only code with protected access' .

Comment: @Sam: So you're saying that you don't know what `protected` means?

Comment: I know what the protected means in the context of inheritance but what do you mean by 'only code with protected access' ? I get lost here. Do you mean classes that are inherited protectedly?

Comment: @Sam: Then you don't really *know* what protected means "in the context of inheritance". If you have class `A` which has a subobject (member or base class) that is declared `protected`, what that means is that the only ones who can access that object are members of `A`, members of a class derived from `A`, or friends of `A`. Code that can "access" "protected" subobjects can be said to "have protected access".

Comment: You're right. I didn't know what protected means. It gets really complicated with friends come into play. 

Something came to my mind, in your last comment above you said "It has access to the private members of Base, but to get access to them, it has to see Base". but why when Derived inherits protectedly from Base if we declare main() as friend in Derived as well as Base, main can get to see all the members of two classes? I mean the inheritance is sill protected ! how come main() can see Base through friend? I thought friend only works for data members and methods not Base itself.

Comment: @Sam: "*I thought friend only works for data members and methods not Base itself.*" There's a reason I said "subobject" and not "data member".

Comment: Thanks. This is my last question: even though I declared 'friend int main();' in the Derived class and remove 'friend int main();' from the Base class and the inheritance is protected . Why I still get one error which is on 'd.k ;' I thought this friendship has effect on the entire subobject  but it seems the friendship relationship doesn’t provide us access to the private members of the Base class.

Comment: @Sam: Remember my first sentence: `d.i` is a fiction. The access scope of `private` is different from the scope of `protected`. That's why they are different keywords. `private` only allows access by members of the type or by friends of that type. Derived classes need not apply.

Comment: I see. That "by friends of that type" is a good point that I didn't know about. thank you so much for your responses. I need to study more. It easily gest complicated.